# Get params from typeOf ngrx effects

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have something like this

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new TutorialActions.GetTutorials(1, 20));
}

export class GetTutorials implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_TUTORIALS
  constructor(public number: number, public offset: number) {}
}
```

And then i have effects like this

```js
export class TutorialEffects {
  loadTutorials$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(TutorialActions.GET_TUTORIALS),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.tutorialService.getAll(0, 20).pipe(
          map((tutorial: Tutorial[]) => new TutorialActions.SuccesGetTutorials(tutorial)),
          catchError((error) => of (error))
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

The problem is in `ofType(TutorialActions.GET_TUTORIALS)`, `this.tutorialService.getAll(0,20)`.

That value should be passed from `ngOnInit` functions and can be dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have access to the action object. So you can access the properties of it.

```js
export class TutorialEffects {
   loadTutorials$ = createEffect(() =>
     this.action$.pipe(
       ofType(TutorialActions.GET_TUTORIALS),
       switchMap((action: any) =>
         this.tutorialService.getAll(action.number, action.offset).pipe(
           map((tutorial: Tutorial[]) => new TutorialActions.SuccesGetTutorials(tutorial)),
           catchError((error) => of (error))
         )
       )
     )
   );
 }
```